# Add HTTP headers to Meteor's whitelist

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor application deployed behind Apache, which is acting as a proxy and authenticates the user via SSO. I have the following piece of code:

```
Meteor.onConnection(connection => console.log(connection.httpHeaders))
```

Apache sends the HTTP header REMOTE_USER but I cannot see the information in Meteor's server-side. I did some research and found out that Meteor whitelists the HTTP headers but it doesn't say how to add to the whitelist. Does anybody know?

Or is there another way of getting the information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used **meteor-headers** to accomplish this. Don't know if still works.

You should try https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers

Comment: I've tried it but it seems to not work under Meteor 1.3 and 1.4, anymore. Thanks for the suggestion!